# Stable sums from a set of data series

Tags: time-series, combinatorics

I have a set of daily data series spanning years of data representing different types of calls to a call centre. This data series are individually not constant, but I have been asked to find combinations of some of them that may be stable in time in the medium and long term (without having any better definition of what stable means). Ideally covering as many calls as possible.

The motivation for this is that from week to week some of the people of the call centre have too much calls to assist, and the following week, they may run out of them. Even if it is known in advance that this is going to happen, we would need to find combinations of data series which may be more stable so that we may give an steady amount of work to the people instead of having highs and lows

Does this problem already have a name or is there any theory or framework already developed so as to try those things instead of beginning from scratch with a brute force approach?

This is an example of how they look like:
[image]

Comment: That sounds like cointegration, search this site! Can you show us some time series plots, include them in your post as an edit.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks! I'll have a look at that topic. I'm not very confident that a perfect solution exists, but will try to see if something can be done about it

Comment: Looking at the plots, I am not so sure this is about cointegration.  Your series might well  be stationary. Can you explain what you mean by the series not being stable. If by stable you mean *nearly constant*, you could try PCA (Principal Component Analysis) and choose components with small eigenvalues!

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't explain it properly. From week to week some of the people of the call centre have too much calls to assist, and the following week, they may run out of them. Even if it is known in advance that this is going to happen, we wonder whether there are combinations of data series which may be more stable so that we may give an steady amount of work to the people instead of having highs and lows. Sorry, I said "in the long term" but maybe that needed clarification @kjetilbhalvorsen

Comment: Please add that explanation to The post as an edit

Comment: There exist statistical tests for the constancy of a mean (it's called changepoint detection). So what you could do is come up with some combinations of these series and then run a hypothesis test to test for a constant mean. This paper may be a good starting point: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1467-9892.2012.00819.x .